# Redirect to index

Tags: reactjs, react-router

With react-router **v. 2.8.1** I am not able to redirect to the index page. I'd like to redirect there after a successful login from **/login**

I use

```
static contextTypes = {
        router: React.PropTypes.object
   };

   ...

   this.context.router.push('/');
```

I have also tried the deprecated `hashHistory`:

```
router.hashHistory.push('/');
```

In case I provide any other path, e.g. **messages** it redirects me correctly.

```
this.context.router.push('/messages');
```

How to redirect to the index using `react-router`?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't redirecting again from `/`?

Comment: What version of `react-router` do you have ?

Comment: `react-router` version is 2.8.1. I solved it using `this.context.router.push('');` after adding the necessary roles to my user. As @KabirRoy pointed out this was redirecting me to the login screen again. Thx.

Comment: Can you show your router/routes definition?